# EntityFramework does not add dbname with table name

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

My entity framework sends an insert query as follows

```
insert into students (
`studentCode`, 
`surname`)
VALUES ('djs', 'andy');
```

MySql database needs the query as

```
insert into ge.students (
`studentCode`, 
`surname`)
VALUES ('djs', 'andy');
```

ge is the dbname

so it gives me error
**Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your entity class, see if the follow table annotation/attribute helps:

```
[Table("students", Schema = "ge")]
public class Student
{
    public Student()
    { 
    }
    public int studentCode { get; set; }     
    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```